# Scalar deleting destructor

Tags: c++, polymorphism, destructor, scalar, delete-operator

I have a piece of code (from a DLL) that looks like this:

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual ~A();
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        ~B();
}

~A() {
    // #1
}

~B() {
    // #2
}
```

When I use `delete an_instance_of_B` I get `scalar deleting destructor`. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 10):

Don't `delete` an instance of `B`. You're supposed to use `delete` on pointers to object allocated with `new`:

```
B b;
delete b;   //wrong

//.........

B* pB = new pB;
delete pB;  //okay

//.........

B justThis; //best
```

Comment: @dan Post the callstack in the question, along with some actual code.